# Unity: just keep loading infitely on "Application.Reload" every time i enter in play mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

### The problem

Hi, I have been experiencing this kind of **loading infitely** on the window screen: **"Application.Reload"** since two or three days ago. This just happened **spontaneously** without any reason. I have been seaching for a solution, but the uniques fixes i had found are not working for me.

The unique **not permanet** solution that I came up is just use the **Task Manager** and **close up** Unity.

### The possible fixes that I have tried:

- "Just locate the **project folder** in the system explorer and click on **properties**" (This only work one time per application or maybe it just do not work.)
- "You can check to see if there is any place in your project path that is not in English" (It just do not work.)

These are the fixes that I have tried.

### Example of the problem

Meanwhile I am writing this question, I want to **re-confirm** this is a infinite load. So I **open up** my Unity Proyect, enter in the **Play Mode** and write this question.

This is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTA48.png

Edit: the image actually shows the longest time i have been waiting. (1:48:34hs)

Thank in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Sorry about the image, the only way that I can use is a link.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, this problem persist as well in any Unity Operation, it can happen on Reload, Importing, Asset Indexer, etc. Is just a problem that doesn't affect Unity, and devs marked it as WNF (We'll Not Fix).

I have been struggling with this problem for some years now and the only solution I found was to close it from Task Manager and reopen it.

Comment: Wow!, this is quite odd and rare, I hope that some day this just fix of nothing. In anycase thank you for your help.